# How do I sum a column using using only a capped portion of certain cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to create yearly sums based on a column of data where certain cells are capped in the way they are contributing to the yearly sum. I need the formula to do a few things:

- Ensure it is only summing data that comes from the correct date range for the given year
- Certain cells' values need to be capped based on 2 parameters. I will give the point at which the cell should stop contributing to the sum and the value for which the cell should again begin contributing to the sum (these parameters will change based on the year the formula is summing)
  For example: Point at which the cell should stop contributing - `500,000`.   Point at which the cell should begin contributing again - `1,000,000`. If the cell contains the number `1,200,000`, it should contribute `700,000` to the total sum.

The formula I attempted to put together is below:

```
=SUMIF($A$12:$A$500,A3,(IF($E$12:$E$500<=P3,$E$12:$E$500,(IF($E$12:$E$500>(P3+Q3),$E$12:$E$500-Q3,P3))))))
```

I am given a `Value error` when attempting to use this formula.

Comment: The `#VALUE!` is likely because the third argument of the `SUMIF` function should be a `range`, and yours appears to be an array. Without sample data (as text which can be copy/pasted), and at least a screenshot of desired output from that data, I cannot assist further.

Comment: it might be easer to build a helper column that is doing your `IF` part of your formula. You should be able to use a MIN()+MAX() formulation to make it easier to read.